# how to query a dataset in c#

Tags: c#, sql

This is my first post, so please be gentle :)

I'm working on the automatic register for my university project. I use RFID scanner to scan student ID tag and a DB created in Access. I use C# and dataGridView to show my DB tables.

I am trying to write an SQL query which will return a current sessionID for each scanned tagID, by compering date/time saved in DB with current date/time. My question is: how do i do it? I have googled my problem but could not find the answer I was looking for (probably due to the complicated structure of my tables). Maybe you will be able to help.

My tables are structured as followed:

```
Student
fields Name -> Data type
=========================
(PK) tagID -> number
studentID -> text
(FK) courseID -> number
studentName -> text

Course
=========================
(PK) courseID -> number
courseName -> text

CourseModule
=========================
(FK) courseID -> number
(FK) moduleID -> text

Module
=========================
(PK) moduleID -> text
courseName -> text

ModuleSession
=========================
(FK) moduleID -> text
(FK) sessionID -> text

Session
=========================
(PK) sessionID -> text
sessionStartDate -> date
sessionTimeStart -> time
sessionTimeEnd -> time

Attendance
=========================
(FK) tagID -> number
(FK) sessionID -> text
(FK) scanningTime -> date/time
```

Comment: If you dont have much experience I suggest you to take a look at realtional databases and see how they work

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. This is not a real question as it does not demonstrate that you've actually tried the problem yourself yet. The community generally doesn't respond positively to "code it for me" type questions. It's advisable to search around, find the thousands of examples of SQL queries, try the problem yourself, and come back with a more specific question.

Comment: OK, understood. I have used a numerous ways to do it but without success. I have created a similar query in Access (to get all sessionID's for the given tagID) but what i need is to "pass" the tag ID as a parameter to the query (after the tag has been scanned)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you want. Here is a basic database querying with c#.

Use DataAdapters to populate your DataTables with your SQL query.

```
            using (SqlConnection conn = Connection)
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT *
                                        FROM [Your Tables]
                                        WHERE TagID = @TagID";

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TagID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier) { Value = variableName});

                    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                        adapter.Fill(dataSet, "datatablename");

                        return dataSet.Tables["datatablename"];
                    }
                }
            }
```

Then you can get values from your DataTable by looping through it or using Lambda functions

Or you can bind the DataTable to your GridView by using the GridView properties

What you want to do with the DataTable I am not sure.

Comment: This is a really good example, thanks for this. What I would like to do is to get the active session for the tagID, compare the session time and date with the current date/time and populate this information in the Attendance table, along with the time of scanning. I use DGV to show my tables.

Comment: So are you asking for the sql query? or do you want to pull the data out of the DataTable?

Comment: To be honest, Im not entirely sure what I need. I have a DB populated with the data, and I need to get the sessionID for the particular tagID within the given timeframe, so I think i need SQL query to retrive this data...

Comment: You need sql first, then you'll need @SpaceApple 's code sample to fill your datagrid :)

Comment: @user2362925 - I think you need to pick up a book and give it a read.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, please change your session start & end time to be a complete datetime because using 3 fields to specify a start/end period make queries very complex.
If you introduce this change, and if I've correctly understood what you want, this query will return the result you need:

```
SELECT s.sessionID
FROM Attendance a
  INNER JOIN Session s ON a.sessionID = s.sessionID
WHERE a.scanningTime BETWEEN s.sessionTimeStart AND s.sessionTimeEnd
```

If you don't want to change the field, then you need to construct a start & end datetime that can be used in the query

EDIT
After some check,  the query with the DATEADD will not work. If you still want to use the 3 fields this should works:

```
WHERE a.scanningTime BETWEEN (s.sessionStartDate + s.sessionTimeStart) AND (s.sessionStartDate + s.sessionTimeEnd)
```

But with a condition: the Time part of your sessionStartDate column is always zero.
You could force this by using a "Date" SQL type for your field (only available with Sql server 2008 or above)

Please note I've typed the query directly and I've not tested if the syntax is completely correct.

Comment: Very usefull, many thanks, will give you vote up as soon as my rep = 15 :)

Comment: I've updated my answer after some check, because I was partially wrong :)